# Добавление в Nuget пакет для C# нативных библиотек

Tags: c#, nuget, native

Есть проект, который использует либу на cpp через DllImport. (допустим Qt5Core)

Вопрос первый, а как ее корректно добавить? Я добавил просто как файл и build action выставил как content -copy if newer.
Сразу же вылазит первая проблема, nuget pack выполняется с ошибкой:

**ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ. Issue: Assembly outside lib folder.
ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ. Description: The assembly 'content\lib\Qt5Core.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as reference when the package is installed into a project.
ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ. Solution: Move it into the 'lib' folder if it should be referenced.**

я могу открыть nupkg файл и ручками перенести нативную dll в папку lib,
но тогда пакет не ставится уже в целевой solution через nuget package manager с ошибкой:

**Failed to add reference to 'Qt5Core'.
Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.**

быстрый гуглеж ответов не дал, подскажите пожалуйста, куда копать?

Comment: А каким образом упаковка происходит? nuget.exe pack, NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack, etc?

Comment: @UserName nuget pack

Comment: Тогда можно попробовать через `PackagePath` свойство указать местоположение библиотеки в пакете: `<PackagePath>build\native\etc</PackagePath>` - [\lib is not used in this case - NuGet cannot directly add references to a C++ project](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/native-packages)

Comment: Для автоматизации работы с `Native Package` можно использовать [CoApp](http://coapp.org/tutorials/building-a-package.html).

Comment: @UserName я уже куда их только не клал в пакете, и в build и просто в корень и в подпапки с архитектурой, ошибка при установке пакета всегда одна и та же((